# Button inside div and label: why is clicking anywhere in the div triggering the button?

Tags: html

Given the following HTML snippet, why is the button clickable from anywhere in the div?

```html
<label>
    <div style="height: 100vh">
        <button type="button">Hmm?</button>
    </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the `<label>` tag, see this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#try_it)
Essentially, since the input (button in this case) is placed inside the label there is an implicit link between the two.
Doing this results in the following:

> - When a user clicks or touches/taps a label, the browser passes the focus to its associated input (the resulting event is also raised for the input). **That increased hit area for focusing the input** provides an advantage to anyone trying to activate it — including those using a touch-screen device.

Therefore since there is a div that is covering the whole screen within the label, clicking anywhere on the screen means clicking on the label and therefore implicitly clicking the button.